# CoordinatorLayout.Behavior causes onStartNestedScroll(..) twice

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an issue.

I use CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollView inside. NestedScrollView indludes TextView + RecyclerView. I also have AppBarLayout with attached behavior.

When I interact with RecyclerView, behavior works fine. But if I try interact with TextView, behavior causes onStartNestedScroll(..) then onStopNestedScroll(..) and onStartNestedScroll(..) again.

Why this is happens? How can I prevent it?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aspot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:background="#39868686"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:padding="100dp"
                android:text="Some text"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
             app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.coordinatorbehavior.ScrollingBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="AppBarLayout"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ScrollingBehavior is very simple.

```
public class ScrollingBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<AppBarLayout> {

public ScrollingBehavior() {
}

public ScrollingBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    boolean started = nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    Log.d("log", "onStartNestedScroll: " + started);
    return started;
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target) {
    Log.d("log", "onStopNestedScroll");
    super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117872229 for this.

Comment: As I remember I didn't find solution. And I don't need it for now

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `NestedScrollView`.

**Update your layout as below:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="AppBarLayout"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aspot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:background="#39868686"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:padding="100dp"
                android:text="Some text"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It is not decision for me, because I use custom behavior. I have different behavior for AppBarLayout.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukvuln3e0u01doc/device-2017-05-25-140824.mp4?dl=0

As you can see, when I take scrolling from the header it is glitching because have some gap in onNested(..) event

Comment: have you tried app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to NestedScrollView  in your own layout?